# Why in sly in python does it say illegal character?

Tags: python, lexer, python-3.7

I am getting

```
sly.lex.LexError: Illegal character '0' at index 0
```

when I run my code
That's only part of the error.
I am using sly in python

Here is my lexer:

```
import sly
from sly import Lexer
class mylexer(Lexer):
  tokens = { NAME, EXPR, ASSIGN, EQUALS, NUM, STRING, }
  literals = { '(', ')', '{', '}' }
  ignore = '\t\n'
  NAME = r'[A-Z_a-z][a-zA-Z_0-9-]*'
  EXPR = r'([0-9]+\d?[-\+\*/^]+)+'
```

Here is the file I ran:

```
from lexer import mylexer
data = open("file.in").read()
lexer = mylexer()
for tok in lexer.tokenize(data):
  print('type=%r, value=%r' % (tok.type, tok.value))
```

Here is file.in:

```
0*5
```